# In Mathematica, How calculate P(A) where P is a polynomial and A is a square matrix?

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica, algebra

supose i define a matrix like this:

```
A= {{1,1},{2,2}}
```

and now want to compute A^2 + 3A - 3Id, where a^2 is of course A.A

The syntax in mathematica for doing this is:

```
MatrixPower[A,2] + 3A + 3 IdentityMatrix[2]
```

Is it posible to change de operators behavior in order to be able to write

```
A^2 + 3A - 3Id
```

and get the correct answer ?

Or alternatively

```
applyPoly[x + 3x + 3, x, A]
```

or something like this ?

I was tring some aproaches, but i couldn't do it.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: When you ask about changing the operator behavior, do you mean that you'd like to enter, for instance, `A^2` and have Mathematica understand this?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean.

Comment: I'm out of time to do this question justice (family is pulling me away) but you should look at `Unprotect` to allow changes to an operator, and `;/` to specify conditions for a definition.  The use something like `m_^n_ := MatrixPower[m,n];/MatchQ[Dimension[m], {n_, n_}]`... or something like that.  This is all from distant memory, so take only the flavor of how it's done, don't trust the specifics!  When I get back I'll see if it's still unanswered and if not, I'll make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote your applyPoly function as follows. `A_?MatrixQ` checks that the input `A` is indeed a matrix, the input `var` is the polynomial variable which in your question is `x`. The variable `c` contains a list of coefficients of your polynomial, starting from power zero.

```
applyPoly[poly_, var_, A_?MatrixQ] :=
    With[{c = CoefficientList[poly, var]}, 
    c.MapIndexed[MatrixPower[A, #2[[1]]-1]&, c]]
```

In version 9, you could use `MatrixFunction` as in

```
MatrixFunction[#^2+3#-3&,A]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want Mathematica to interpret A^2 as MatrixPower[A, 2], this definitely involves overloading standard definitions which is generally not good.

The approach I suggest aslo slightly modifies standard definitions but feels more acceptable:

```
OverHat[x_] := operator[x]

Format[operator[x_]] := OverscriptBox[x, "^"] // DisplayForm

Times[o_operator, oRest__operator] ^:=
 operator[Dot @@ Identity @@@ Hold[o, oRest]]

Plus[o_operator, oRest__operator] ^:=
 operator[Plus @@ Identity @@@ Hold[o, oRest]]

Times[n_?NumberQ, operator[m_?MatrixQ]] ^:=
 operator[Times[n, m]]

Plus[n_?NumberQ, operator[m_?MatrixQ]] ^:=
 operator[Plus[Times[n, IdentityMatrix[Length[m]]], m]]

Power[operator[m_?MatrixQ], n_] ^:=
 operator[MatrixPower[m, n]]
```

`operator` homomorphically maps algebra of Matrices (in the sense of Mathematica) to algebra of some abstract operators. Since it acts homomorphically w.r.t. `Plus`, `Times` and `Power`, you can easily apply polynomials to operators.

Operator corresponding to expression A will be printed as Â. You can also input operators this way, i.e., “A, Ctrl+&, “^”, Ctrl+Space”. **The Unicode char Â that I use here and below is not the same as Mathematica's OverHat[A].**

Now you can do things like

```
x^2 + 3 x - 3 /. x -> Â
```

for symbolical operators. Or perform calculations with coordinates:

```
In[1]:= A = {{2, -20, -10}, {0, 4, 1}, {0, -6, -1}};
In[2]:= x^3 - 5 x^2 + 8 x - 4 /. x -> Â
```

which will eveluate to zero operator (this is charateristic polynomial for ). Please note that it will be a zero operator, not a zero matrix, although it will look almost like one, but with a hat over it, which in turn would look like a hat over the middle zero. (This bug can be fixed.)

The definition

```
operator[m_?MatrixQ][v_List] := m.v
```

makes it possible then to apply operators (as well as polynomials applied to operators) to vectors:

```
In[3]:= Â[{0, -1, 2}]
Out[3]= {0, -2, 4}
```

(eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue 2)

```
In[4]:= (Â - 2)[{0, -1, 2}]
Out[4]= {0, 0, 0}
```

I haven't implemented solid error-checking but I hope you got the idea and will be able to make improvements if you like it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be better to use a matrix form of Horner's rule for calculating a polynomial. For a polynomial p(x) = a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3 + ..., one extracts the list of coefficients (a, b, c, d, ...)  and calculates recursively

```
h(()) = 0;

h((a, b, c, d, ...)) =  a + x h((b, c, d, ...)).
```

The matrix version would be

```
h(()) = 0;
h((a, b, c, d, ...), A) =  a I +  A. h((b, c, d, ...), A),
```

where I is the identity matrix.  Mathematica code:

```
MatrixHorner[coeffs_, A_] := Module[{size = Length[A]},
If[coeffs == {}, ConstantArray[0, {size, size}],
First[coeffs] IdentityMatrix[size] + A.MatrixHorner[Rest[coeffs], A]]
]

ApplyPoly[p_, var_, A_?MatrixQ] := 
Module[{c = CoefficientList[p, var]},
MatrixHorner[c, A]
]
```

Your example:

```
q = -3 + 3 x + x^2
A = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}
ApplyPoly[q, x,  A]
```

Output:

```
{{3, 6}, {12, 9}}
```

I think the point of this is that many fewer matrix multiplications are involved;  the total number of matrix multiplications done is just the degree of the polynomial.